# Spring + Hibernate: No property findAddresses found for type UserProfile while fetching a list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, graphql

I have a problem with accessing a list of data from an entity on database using Hibernate.

I have an entity `UserProfile` containg some fields, but mostly important:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Address> addresses;
```

The class has lombok's `@Getter`, and a method to add address:

```
public void addProfileAddress(Address address) {
    addresses.add(address);
}
```

Now, because we want ony one-way relation, the class `Address` looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE addresses SET deleted = true, updated_at = current_date WHERE id = ?")
public class Address extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5034153190245766924L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Setter
    @Column(name = "country", nullable = false)
    private String country;

    @Setter
    @Column(name = "state", nullable = false)
    private String state;

    @Setter
    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false)
    private String city;

    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.AvoidFieldNameMatchingTypeName")
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;


    public Address(Address address) {}
}
```

I have a UserProfileRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserProfileRepository extends AuditableRepository<UserProfile> {

    List<Address> findAddresses(Long id);

}
```

But when I try to run the code (with an GraphQL request:

```
extend type Query {
    userProfiles: [UserProfile]
    addresses(id: ID): [Address]
    userProfile(id: ID): UserProfile
}
```

Using GraphQL Query resolver method:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER', 'USER')")
public Set<Address> getAddresses(Long id) {
    return userProfileRepository.findAddresses(id).stream().map(Address::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with 
name 'userProfileRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract 
java.util.List 
com.l4a.app.infrastructure.database.repository.UserProfileRepository.findAddresses(java.
lang.Long)! No property findAddresses found for type UserProfile!
```

Can anyone help me with this one? I am stuck...

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

When I rename the Repository method to `findByAddresses` I get:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily 
initialize a collection of role: 
com.l4a.app.domain.userprofile.UserProfile.addresses, could 
not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all collections are lazy loaded meaning spring/hibernate do not load the models during query. You will have to add `JOIN FETCH` to your query:

```
@Query("SELECT addr FROM UserProfile user JOIN FETCH user.addresses addr WHERE user.id = ?1")
Set<Address> findAddresses(Long id);
```

If you want to have a uni-directional relationship where `UserProfile` have access to the `Address` but not visa versa you can do something like the following:

Add `userId` to the `Address` table and corresponding Entity:

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE addresses SET deleted = true, updated_at = current_date WHERE id = ?")
public class Address extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5034153190245766924L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Setter
    @Column(name ="userId", nullable = true)
    private Long userId;

    @Setter
    @Column(name = "country", nullable = false)
    private String country;

    @Setter
    @Column(name = "state", nullable = false)
    private String state;

    @Setter
    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false)
    private String city;

    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.AvoidFieldNameMatchingTypeName")
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;


    public Address(Address address) {}
}
```

Create an `AddressRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends AuditableRepository<Address> {

    Set<Address> findByUserId(Long userId);
}
```

Then you can get your Address set from your method like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER', 'USER')")
public Set<Address> getAddresses(Long id) {
  return addressRepository.findByUserId(id);
}
```

Comment: I got a bit further, but now I get: `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: user_profiles is not mapped [SELECT addr FROM user_profiles user JOIN FETCH user.addresses addr WHERE user.id = ?1]`

Comment: You want to use the class name not the table name in the query: `UserProfile` instead of `user_profile` I updated my answer to reflect it. I had a typo

Comment: A TINY bit further... now I get: `Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=addr,role=userprofile.UserProfile.addresses,tableName=addresses,tableAlias=address2_,origin=user_profiles userprofil0_,columns={userprofil0_.id ,className=address.Address}}] [SELECT addr FROM userprofile.UserProfile user JOIN FETCH user.addresses addr WHERE user.id = ?1]`

Comment: I have removed `FETCH` from the query, and added `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` to the UserProfile class to the @OneToMany annotation and it seems to work...

Comment: That will work too. The only thing with that is every time you query a `UserProfile` it will always fetch the associated addresses as well, thus will slow things down somewhat. Looking at the code i see there is no association `UserProfile` Reference in your `Address` class. That is what the error you're getting is referencing.

Comment: So is there a possibility to make one-directional relation? So userorofile nas relation to adressses, but addresses dont have relation to userprofile?

Comment: If you stored the userId in the the `Address` table itll be a quasi uni-direction relationship. See my answer edit.

Comment: I used the solution You added for one-directional relation and it works like a charm!